# connect activitys

Tags: android, imagebutton

Can some one tell me were i am going wrong. i have three activity's that i want to connect togever. This code is my first java file and first xml file. i think my onclick code some where is not right. my end result is that all 3 activity connect with 3 image buttons...thank

java 1.code
package my.hope;

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.content.Intent;
    public class NewhopeActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    myImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        intent intent = new intent(Newhopeactivity.this, Act2.class);
        startActivity(intent);

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
    }  
  );  
}
```

}

xml.code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/bt" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
    android:onClick="Act2"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put the startActivity() into the actual onClick() method.

```
myImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


        public void onClick(View v) {
            intent intent = new intent(Newhopeactivity.this, Act2.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
myImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    intent intent = new intent(Newhopeactivity.this, Act2.class);
    startActivity(intent);

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
}
```

to

```
ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
myImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub          
            Intent intent = new intent(Newhopeactivity.this, Act2.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much it worked for me . i did the same for all three activity and it work .whats the bast way to put a button on all three activity pages that give the option of going back